# I've a problem when I use the Sleep?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

why in my code, the `TextView` does not take except the last count.
the result just is: `counter= 4`

```
int i =0;

while (i< 5) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep((i*1000));
        mText.setText("counter"+ i);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // mText does not show
    mText.setText("counter= "+ i);
    i = i +1;
}
```

Comment: When I followed step by step implementation of the program,then I noted that the component TextView does not take the value of the variable "i" at each step, just in the last step.

Comment: I think he is trying to ask why doesn't the text change every second. He sees only the last one, `counter = 4`

Answer (score 3):

You are blocking the UI thread when your app sleeps, so the screen is not redrawn, hence you don't see the text changes until your loop ends.

> **The UI thread**
>
> When an application is launched, the system creates a thread called
>   "main" for the application. The main thread, also called the UI
>   thread, is very important because it is in charge of dispatching the
>   events to the appropriate widgets, including drawing events. It is
>   also the thread where your application interacts with running
>   components of the Android UI toolkit.
>
> For instance, if you touch the a button on screen, the UI thread
>   dispatches the touch event to the widget, which in turn sets its
>   pressed state and posts an invalidate request to the event queue. The
>   UI thread dequeues the request and notifies the widget to redraw
>   itself.
>
> This single-thread model can yield poor performance unless your
>   application is implemented properly. Specifically, if everything is
>   happening in a single thread, performing long operations such as
>   network access or database queries on the UI thread will block the
>   whole user interface. No event can be dispatched, including drawing
>   events, while the long operation is underway. From the user's
>   perspective, the application appears hung. Even worse, if the UI
>   thread is blocked for more than a few seconds (about 5 seconds
>   currently) the user is presented with the infamous "application not
>   responding" (ANR) dialog.
>
> If you want to see how bad this can look, write a simple application
>   with a button that invokes Thread.sleep(2000) in its OnClickListener.
>   The button will remain in its pressed state for about 2 seconds before
>   going back to its normal state. When this happens, it is very easy for
>   the user to perceive the application as slow.
>
> To summarize, it's vital to the responsiveness of your application's
>   UI to keep the UI thread unblocked. If you have long operations to
>   perform, you should make sure to do them in extra threads (background
>   or worker threads).

More info:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

That is the problem. And `AsyncTask` is (one) solution:

> **AsyncTask**
>
> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
>   thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.
>
> An asynchronous task is defined by a computation that runs on a
>   background thread and whose result is published on the UI thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: do you think that we can use timer to timer as solution

Answer (score 2):

First, it would be a good idea to change the text before sleeping.

Second, if you do this in a separate thread, you have, nevertheless, to manipulate a widget in the ui thread. Try this :

instead of

```
mText.setText("counter"+ i);
```

try

```
runOnUIThread( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mText.setText("counter"+ i);
    }
});
```

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: I suppose it is just the other way - the whole loop must be done in a second loop so the UI thread is not blocked.

Answer (score 1):

"while (i <= 5)" will make it go on till five.
Another solution is to make "i" 1 to start with, instead of 0.

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop (inside a non-UI thread):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++}{
    try {
        Thread.sleep((i*1000));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mText.setText("counter"+ i);
        }
    });  
}
```

Comment: While the sleep will probably allow time the UI thread to run (and the screen to paint) that's not guaranteed so you may or may not see 1 through 5.

Answer (score 0):

Many answers here gave you all the information you need to achieve what you want but it may be difficult to understand.

I will propose you below a new way to achieve it, maybe easier. But I want to underline that you should understand what people wrote, my previuos post and the one from @LAS_VEGAS at least.

Here is something easy : use a handler.

add a data member like

Handler handler = new Handler();

then on click :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++}{
    handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mText.setText("counter"+ i);
        }
    }, i * 1000 );  
}
```

I don't have access to my very own computer right now and fear this may not compile due to a non final variable used inside a annonymous inner class. So you could also try to build a named inner class like this in your main java class :

```
public class ButtonTimerThread implements Runnable
{
     privqte int i =0;

     public ButtonTimerThread( int i)
     {
           this.i = i;
     }//cons

     public void run()
     {
            mText.setText("counter"+ i);
     }//met
}//class
```

qnd then you click listener method would look like :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++}{
    handler.postDelayed( new ButtonTimerThread( i ), i * 1000 );  
}
```

As your handler will be created by the UI thread, it will be able to update UI. The handler offers the advantage to have a delay mechanism that doesn't block the UI thread that is reacting to your click action.

I hope this helps,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

Generally, good solutions to problems with sleep() involve stopping using sleep(). Blocking the UI thread is always a very bad idea. It makes you application's UI non-responsive.

In your case you want an event to run every second. The correct way to implement that is with a timer.